# How to set a global variable range usable in multiple procedures/modules

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large series of ranges (>500) that I have defined in my workbook using general declarations: `Public r1 As Range, Public r2 As Range` etc. Each range always refers to the same cell in the document. ie r1 always refers to Sheet 1, B2.

Many of my events take action on all 500 ranges individually and I am frequently bumping into the 64k module memory limit because I have to declare the range for each variable in each module which I have been doing using: `Set r1 = Sheets("Sheet 1").Range"B2"`

Is there a way to declare the ranges globally, and then call them freely in all of the various modules that use them? This would free up 30k of memory for each module.

Comment: Would Named ranges work?

Comment: In order of preference: 1) Named Ranges, 2) a class, 3) a subroutine that sets them, called from each routine that needs them

Comment: I tried using named ranges but when I try to call the range I get an error that says compile error, argument non optional. I'm not sure how a class would function. For the calling each from a routine, I think that is the same idea as was suggested below that I have been trying to make work for weeks with no success.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure there is something terribly wrong with the macro design if it really needs more than 500 Range variables, so I would recommend https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for that.

The general recommended way is to add them as Named Ranges as those are saved in the workbook the first time they are added, and auto-adjusted if rows/columns are inserted before them or other similar changes.
You can add Named Ranges to the currently active workbook like this:

```
Names.Add "n1", "='Sheet 1'!B2"  ' results in error if already added

Range("n1").Value2 = 42          ' sample use
```

Another alternative might be global string constants:

```
Public Const r1$ = "'Sheet 1'!B2"

Sub test()
    Range(r1).Value2 = 42
End Sub
```

Comment: Range names that are the same as cell addresses are not allowed

Comment: thanks @jkpieterse I wasn't sure if it will be allowed without the c

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create a sub that sets all the ranges and then following subs just refer to the variable.

```
Option Explicit

Public r1 As Range

Sub setup()
Set r1 = Sheet1.Range("a1")
End Sub

Sub test()
r1.Value = 1
End Sub

Sub test2()
r1.Value = 2
End Sub
```

Comment: I've seen this suggested several times but can never seem to get it to work. I built a test file using the following code which would use two buttons to change the value in the cell between two options which is an extremely simplified version of what the macro does. The code I used was:
    Sub setup()
    r1 = Sheet1.Range("a1")
    End Sub

    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    r1.Value = 1
    End Sub

    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    r1.Value = 2
    End Sub

But when I click the buttons I get runtime error 424.

Comment: if you just copy and paste the code I posted into a new module does it work for you?

also the setup needs a `set` to set the range of `r1`

Comment: It does not. I receive Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: first you need to run the setup sub, that should fix that error

Comment: I was finally able to get this to work. I had to add Call setup into each of the other subs, and it now allows me to a separate sub for each function. Thanks for all of your help.